# When click on item can't do this.setState REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the form with different inputs  (an example is down) when I click someone from them and if another input is open I want to close them.

Maybe someone can say where is my an error?
Thanks!

My code look:

```
class SignUp extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        selectedCode: false,
      };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
    }
    handleClickOutside(e) {
      if (e.target.id !== "code") {
        this.setState({
          selectedCode: false // here is an error
        });
      } else {
        console.log("YES CODE");
      }
    }
render (){
  return (
    <form >
      <input .../> 
      <input id="code" .../>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: Is it showing any error in browser console?

Comment: You need to bind `this` to your event handler. On common way to do that is to use `bind` in your constructor: `this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);` See the linked question's answers for details. (Sometimes people use an arrow function, but having the method on the prototype works better with test frameworks.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside.bind(this));
```